# Motorola EMDK for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: motorola-emdk

So, now that Visual Studio 2013 supports the Compact Edition AppBuilder.. Does anyone know where to find the right EMDK or how to create a new solution for a Motorols/Symbol MC9090 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Motorola/Symbol EMDK for .NET only is only supported up to VS 2005/2008 since Windows Mobile SDKs only have support up to VS 2008.

This is the most recent EMDK release, check the release notes for installation requirements: [EMDK for .NET](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/emdk-for-net.html)

Update: Fixed link to new support site.

Comment: @Crono Updated the link to their new support site.

Answer (score 0):

We still use Visual Studio 2008 for our EMDK development, however, I believe Microsoft has added .NET 3.9 support for Visual Studio 2015.

While the EMDK doesn't support Visual Studio 2015, the references would still work you just wouldn't have the toolbox objects. Not sure how big an issue that would be for you but we've never used them!

So if you started a new project, you should be able to select the EMDK dlls required for your project if you have the EMDK installed on your machine. You will need to select the correct processor architecture for your device (I'm guessing armv4i as most Motorola kit seems to be this)

You also may need to work with .NET 3.9 exclusively which might give you a headache getting that onto the MC9090. You'll not only need to install but you'll need to make it stick for a cold boot. This will either need a platform build or some very creative splicing of the .NET 3.9 CAB file and some SymScript! :)